# what relationships between time sequence and nyquist bin or Dc bin?

Tags: fft, digital-communications

I worked on fft recently, and I found kiss_fft code have some comments I do not understand.

> 1. The sum of tdc.r and tdc.i is the sum of the input time sequence.
>    yielding DC of input time sequence
> 2. The difference of (tdc.r - tdc.i) is the sum of the input (dot product) [1,-1,1,-1...
>    yielding Nyquist bin of input time sequence

I know the 1. dc is `tdc.r + tdc.i`,and also equal to the sum of time sequence.

for example :

```
timedata[16] = {14.00000,-11.00000,15.00000,47.00000,41.00000,32.00000,5.00000,2.00000,-7.00000 ,6.00000,-2.00000,-13.00000,12.00000,5.00000,2.00000,10.00000};
```

fft result :

```
158.000000000000 + 0.00000000000000i
…
…
2.000000000000000 + 0.000000000000000i
```

So the freq value `158+0i` (DC bin) is sum of time sequence data.

But the 2. comment: I can not understand how to find the releations between time & freq.

How is the frequency value `2+0i` (Nyquist bin) calculated?

Comment: It's not only guys here, also ladies. Anyway, I'm cleaning up your question a bit. There's a lot of spurious symbols in there.

Comment: well, the FFT is just a fast impementation of the DFT; so, that's how it's calculated; just insert bin number into the DFT formula. You know the DFT formula, right?

Comment: yes , I know the DFT formula.

Comment: well, then insert the bin number (N/2) of the Nyquist bin into the formula, and see which values the term takes that you multiply with your time series.

Comment: thaks Marcus Müller ，I use the DFT formula understand how nyquist Bin calculated.

Comment: cos(π * n) is -1 or 1  ,and then  just do sum.

Comment: exactly. That's also what's written in the text you cite.